# Custom schedule payments with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I want to handle the following use cases with Stripe:

- Charge a customer on a regular schedule where the interval between charges is not a single number, e.g. charge on Tuesdays and Thursdays.
- Charge the same customer at one off instances, e.g. they are regularly charged on Tuesdays and Thursdays but for this particular week, Saturday also.

Can I fulfill these use cases with Stripe without needing to generate a new token each time (i.e. take the payer's card details each time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new card token each time. Card tokens are created client-side, for example via [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements). They allow you to collect card details securely client-side and then simply send the card token id (tok_1234) to your server to charge the card.

When using a token, you have two options. First, you can charge the card once using the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge). Otherwise, if you want the ability to charge the card more than once, you would save the card on a customer. This is covered in details in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

Once a card is saved on a customer, you can use the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to charge that card. You would pass the customer id (cus_123) in the `customer` parameter and if you want a specific card you would also pass the card id (card_abc) in the `source` parameter.

You can try to charge the card as needed on days where you expect a payment. It's up to the cardholder's bank to decide if they want to let the charge go through or not.

Comment: Thanks @koopajah. I thought this was possible, turns out I had just misread the docs previously.